# The images are displayed different with PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, gallery

I have a website and I built a function which displays photos.

The problem is that when I display a gallery with this PHP function ...

```
<?php

function gallery_1()
{
    $picture_ids = array(   1,10,100,101,102,103,
                            104,105,106,107,108,109,
                            11,110,111,112,113,114,
                            115,116,117,118,119,12,
                            120,121,122,123,124,125,
                            126,127,128,129,13,130,
                            131,132,133,134,135,136,
                            137,138,139,14,140,141,
                            142,143,144,145,146,147,
                            148,149,15,150,151,152,
                            153,154,155,156,157,158,
                            159,16,160,161,162,163,
                            164,165,166,167,168,169,
                            17,170,171,172,173,174,
                            175,176,178,18,19,2,
                            20,21,22,23,28,29,
                            3,30,31,32,33,34,
                            35,36,37,38,39,4,
                            40,41,42,43,44,45,
                            46,47,48,49,5,50,
                            51,6,69,7,8,86,
                            87,88,89,9,90,91,
                            92,93,94,95,96,97,
                            98,99);

    $n = 6;  // number of pictures in each row

    echo '<div class="row">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($picture_ids); $i++) 
    {
        // start a new row after each $n pictures
        if (($i > 0) && ($i % $n === 0)) 
        {
            echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
            echo '<div class="row">' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        echo '<article class="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<a href="images/originals/' . $picture_ids[$i] . '.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/' . $picture_ids[$i] . '.jpg" alt="" /></a>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '</article>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

... the gallery looks like this: [Gallery with PHP](http://postimg.org/image/e2qjsgidp/)

But if I write the same code in HTML, so like this ...

```
<div class="row">
    <article class="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">
        <a href="images/originals/1.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </article>
    <article class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">
        <a href="images/originals/10.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/10.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </article>
    <article class="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">
        <a href="images/originals/100.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/100.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </article>
    <article class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">
        <a href="images/originals/101.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/101.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </article>
    <article class="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">
        <a href="images/originals/102.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/102.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </article>
    <article class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">
        <a href="images/originals/103.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/103.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </article>
</div>
```

... the gallery looks like this: [Gallery with HTML](http://postimg.org/image/c0iawnk3d/)

Notice the white space when it's displayed with PHP? What am I doing wrong? If you need some other code or want to se it live in action on website just let me know.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Check the php generated HTML, compare it with the manual written code and look for differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html code 2n article tags(2nd, 4th,...) has "6u$" class instead of "6u". So if you change your php code like below i think it will work as you want.

```
echo '<div class="row">' . PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($picture_ids); $i++) 
{
    // start a new row after each $n pictures
    if (($i > 0) && ($i % $n === 0)) 
    {
        echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<div class="row">' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if($i % 2 === 0)
    {
        echo '<article class="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<article class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '<a href="images/originals/' . $picture_ids[$i] . '.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/' . $picture_ids[$i] . '.jpg" alt="" /></a>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</article>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
```